# SSD very slow copying files

Tags: ssd, hdparm

I'm running Debian 10, and I have 3 SSDs, one of which is an m.2 (nvme), and I'm facing a strange issue when copying files between two internal SSDs, or even inside the same SSD: **the copy  (r/w) speed never exceeds 30 Mb/s**. Copying or moving files between eternal USB drives results in a speed of roughly 100 Mb/s. However, checking with `hdparm`, I got the following results:

```
light@jupiter:~$ sudo hdparm -tT --direct /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing O_DIRECT cached reads:   956 MB in  2.00 seconds = 477.68 MB/sec
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 1516 MB in  3.00 seconds = 504.67 MB/sec
```

and

```
light@jupiter:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB               
    Serial Number:      S3R3NF1JB20052B     
    Firmware Revision:  EMT03B6Q
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0039) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 1   Current = 1
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Asynchronous notification (eg. media change)
       *    Software settings preservation
            Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    reserved 69[4]
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 8min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxx (EDITED)
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 002538
    Unique ID   : xxxxxxxx (EDITED)
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 50 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 30 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

These are my SSDs:

```
light@jupiter:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 960 EVO 250GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BF245E1A-0824-4270-B4DA-2A3C20CFEB82

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 421918719 420868096 200.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 421918720 488396799  66478080  31.7G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6CA2B8F4-5167-4DC2-B732-5F5754A2043D

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F16043FD-A05C-4993-BB2E-B241D66C6E77

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G Linux filesystem
```

and a hdd (don't know if that matter)

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1ER1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3ab64096

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any advice will be welcome!

Comment: Curious. How did you measure the 30Mb/s benchmark?

Comment: Are you mounting with noatime? My data partition mount:  `# Entry for nvme0n1p5 :
UUID=1a44f4af-6780-4bbd-ad0b-6385ed30830b /mnt/data ext4 noatime 0 2`

Comment: @hedgie, 30 Mb/s is the copy speed, if i'm copying a large file (GUI). So I have to try mounting  with noatime? In fstab i'm having this: `UUID=1814d716-3114-4d8b-9257-a272be939545 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=A1FD-E1FA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1`

Comment: What is the copy speed when you copy a file with `pv inputfile > outputfile`?

Comment: It seems to be slower than those 30 Mb/s expected... `599MiB 0:01:13 [8.15MiB/s]`

Comment: Actually my debian is running well and the outputs above are also correct. Copy speed is great, also. But only after i installed `hdparm`. It is that even possible? :)